# Kubuntu 18.10 After returning from suspend, neither built-in keyboard nor the touchpad respond

Tags: kubuntu, 18.10

I am facing problem since i installed Kubuntu 18.10 on my two machines Dell Inspiron I7 and Lenovo thinkpad I5. After returning from suspend, neither built-in keyboard nor the touchpad respond, I have to login via on-screen keyboard and then reboot for them to work - USB mouse works just fine. there is no bug or error found in log. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do it in the following order or you will be left with no input software - basically you need to apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev package then apt-get remove the xserver-xorg-input-libinput package. Restart and you will have sensitivity and acceleration functionality again. 
[Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)