# On 18.04 LTS, how can the TrackPoint driver be changed from libinput back to Synaptics?

Tags: 18.04, synaptics, libinput

I want to change the TrackPoint driver from libinput to Synaptics. I am using a ThinkPad X390 and [I have tried the latest version of the libinput driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168623/how-can-the-trackpoint-driver-be-changed-from-default-libinput-to-a-newer-libinp) and [I have tried to find out why the libinput driver is behaving in a way that makes the TrackPoint unpleasant for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185073/why-is-the-inbuilt-trackpoint-of-this-thinkpad-x390-behaving-differently-to-the) and I now want to change back to Synaptics until libinput is developed further. I have verified that the TrackPoint seems to be running well on 16.04, which features the Synaptics driver.

How might this switch be done from libinput to Synaptics on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

I have already run the following:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04
```

Whether libinput or Synaptics is in use can be ascertained by getting the device name from the output of `xinput --list` and then listing the properties of the device using a command like the following:

```
xinput --list-props "TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint"
```