# Libinput two finger scrolling problem

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, libinput

The problem is the following: my touchpad starts reacting on two-finger scrolling gesture wrong. It seems like it doesn't react on quick gesture at all and very bad on slow gesture. For synpatic everything works well but I like libinput more. What is interesting, after I reboot the laptop, everything works fine until I close the top cover.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Well, it could be a bit hard to help since you didn't post your laptop model, nor libinput version, nor system version. But anyway, a couple of generic advises: α) [try searching libinput issues](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/) for your laptop or touchpad model, β) Ubuntu tends to stick to old, if not ancient, packages, so it may very well be that the issue you're having have been fixed in more-or-less recent libinput. So testing latest libinput would be another step I'd recommend.

Comment: If none of that helped, [report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-bugs-touchpad)

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thank you! Actually, problems started after some Ubuntu updates. Laptop model: Lenovo Thinkpad T580. Libinput version: 1.10.4 . Ubuntu: 18.04.3 LTS. 

Actually, I don't understand how to properly update libinput. Can you provide any instructions?

Comment: To try latest libinput, you can try to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169155/266507), but make sure to read comments as there're some minor issues with the answer that the OP didn't address. libinput 1.10.4 is old indeed, [it's from 2018](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Libinput-1.10.4-Released). ATM latest libinput is 1.14.3. By the way. If you know that the problem started after updates, you could look at the logs what versions of libinput and kernel have you previously had, then try installing these to pin down what exactly brought the problem.