# How to disable mouse debouncing in libinput

Tags: mouse, libinput

Just got a new mouse (glorious model o) and I can get double clicks on it (I click once, get two clicks) however I can only get it to register two clicks on windows. I've done some research and I'm pretty sure that it is `libinput` preventing double clicks by default. Is there any way to make it so that it doesn't try to cancel the double clicks? I know for most people preventing double clicks is useful however I want to be able to double click to get higher CPS in Minecraft and I never manage to accidentally get a double click.

Comment: If you're confident that debounce is the reason for this, you [should report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-mouse-bugs). There's not much sense in working it around locally, since someone else may stumble upon the same problem. Make sure you tested with latest libinput before doing so though.

Comment: For most people double clicks only occur on broken hardware and libinput trys to prevent that from happening, which isn't a bug. However I don't want it to prevent them.

Comment: It may be not a bug for someone else, but it is a bug for owners of the mouse of your model. It's something that needs to be dealt with. libinput [already has a quirk to disable debounce for VMWare mouse](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/158), adding another one for yours should be an easy change.

Comment: Btw, I think I can help you with this though. Can you please execute `libinput list-devices | grep Device`, and tell which one is your mouse name?

Comment: SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse

Comment: Okay, can you please make sure your `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` file has [the following content](https://pastebin.com/GapfkMTb). *(if `/etc/libinput` directory doesn't exist, create it)*. Then you need to restart XServer *(for example, just reboot)*. After that, check whether double click started working. If it didn't, try it again [with this content](https://pastebin.com/r5W4ggsp) *(it's same as previous, but with 2 asterisks added)*.

Comment: Neither seemed to work. Just to make sure I'm referring to double clicking as a method by which you click the mouse once but it sends two clicks signals as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMARykEL32w)

Comment: Oh, okay, so it's not a physical double-click button. Either way, this quirk should've disabled debounce for your mouse, so I'm not sure what else could be the problem. Can you please make an `evemu-record` of the problem *(for example, run `evemu-record > log.txt`)*, and share it somehow, through pastebin or whatever.

Comment: Did 10 clicks most of which were double clicks. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/S2mrV3qk)

Comment: Thanks, indeed this looks as if debounce is still turned on. Odd. Can you please share a `libinput record` of a non-working double-click

Comment: using `libinput debug-events` I recorded 5 double clicks although it looks like there's only 5 regular clicks. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SJVFyudJ)

Comment: Okay, but I need `libinput record` because it says what quirks are currently applied among other stuff.

Comment: I updated to libinput 1.11 (`libinput record` doesn't exist it 1.10) should be working now. 5 double clicks [here](https://pastebin.com/BAgXJSf7)

Comment: Ok, so, this is odd, I see no `quirks:` field, which I have on my system just above `events:` one *(it is empty, but it's there)*. Maybe it's because you have very old libinput, 1.11.1 was released 1.5 years ago, latest stable is 1.14.3. Anyway, a few questions: 1) Did you name the file exactly as `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks`? 2) Did you not add any additional content, such as comments, indentation, spaces around `=` symbol? 3) If you run `libinput debug-events --verbose` and make a click with mouse, does it say about debounce a `DEBOUNCE_STATE_IS_UP` or `DEBOUNCE_STATE_DISABLED`?

Comment: You know what, I figured out why it wasn't working for you! I just thought "could that be that  because you're using very old libinput, it haven't got the option to disable debouncing?". So, quirk grep over sources + `git blame`, and I found that the option to disable it [was only introduced a year ago](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/commit/3a3fd645c). Besides, it seems back then quirks were using another format. Indeed [per this blog post by maintainer](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2018/06/libinput-and-its-device-quirks-files.html), the format was changed in 1.12.

Comment: Updated libinput using the answer to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168623/how-can-the-trackpoint-driver-be-changed-from-default-libinput-to-a-newer-libinp) and it's working now! I didn't read all the comments so `libinput --version` displays it as 1.15.0 whilst synaptic package manager still displays the version as 1.11.1-1 however I don't think this will be an issue and if so I can always refer back to the thread I just mentioned. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, [as of today latest release is 1.15.0](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Libinput-1.15-Released). About package manager: this is odd. I hope you didn't just copy libraries to your system *(e.g. by executing `ninja install`)*, thus bypassing the package manager, did you? Because if you did, those files gonna get overwritten on the next minor update of libinput package.

Comment: I did do that however I will use the method I saw in the comments if I ever notice it stops working:`sudo checkinstall ninja -C builddir/ install`.

Comment: Fun fact: apparently [this is your mouse mentioned](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/hid/hid.git/commit/?h=for-next&id=77a36a3ab4ff17fad23831192e3694a3c5a1750d) in commit for Linux kernel 5.7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reposting the discussion in comments as an answer.

First of, to avoid confusion: OP does not have a hardware button for double-clicks. Rather, the double-click they were referring to is when you tap left mouse button in such a special way so it bounces and causes 2 clicks. I could reproduce it with my mouse too.

This is almost never a wanted behavior, so libinput has a debounce algorithm in place, which detects and discards such bounces. *(and just for the record: it works fine with hardware double-click buttons)*. So OP asked if they can disable it locally.

It is indeed possible via quirk subsystem. Before I go on, I need [to quote documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html):

> For temporary local workarounds, libinput reads the `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` file. Users may add a sections to this file to add a device quirk for a local device but beware that **any modification must be upstreamed** or it may cease to work at any time.
>
> Warning: Model quirks are internal API and may change at any time. No backwards-compatibility is guaranteed. Local overrides should only be used until the distribution updates the libinput packages.

So quirks subsystem is not a configuration API. If you have a problem which can be solved with a quirk, the quirk most likely needs to be upstreamed.

With that said, the following code placed at `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` file helped the OP to get the bouncing-behavior:

```haskell
[SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse]
MatchName=SINOWEALTH Wired Gaming Mouse
ModelBouncingKeys=1
```

The mouse model name is one from `libinput list-devices | grep Device` output. For this to work libinput needs to be at least of 1.12.0 version *(for OP it worked on libinput 1.15.0)*.

Comment: Upvoted. I also think that your comment about what would happen after an update would be beneficial to be included in your answer. A suggested solution (if possible) for this case would be even better!

Comment: @user3140225 well, I specifically didn't mention how to update libinput, because there's another question/answer on that matter, which OP has used to do the update. And that post has similar comments too. I'm hoping one day there either would appear a PPA for latest libinput or somebody will write an answer on how to do installation via `checkinstall`. But I unforunately can do neither because I don't have Ubuntu *(I'm an Archlinux user, and my gf is using Fedora)*.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to execute the following command in terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo mkdir -p /etc/libinput
sudo tee /etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks >/dev/null <<ENDHERE
[Never Debounce]
MatchUdevType=mouse
ModelBouncingKeys=1
ENDHERE
```

Then Reboot your computer

I found this solution on Reddit: [Disable double click prevention](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/ku6gth/disable_double_click_preventionlower_debounce_time/)