# How to disable left touchpad button but keep tap as click

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics, libinput

My laptop's left touchpad button has become loose so it click automatically so I want to disable it.But keep tap as click.

> Earlier I used this solution :
> [How to disable physical touchpad buttons but keep tap as click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073200/how-to-disable-physical-touchpad-buttons-but-keep-tap-as-click)

but after reinstalling Ubuntu the same solution is not working anymore. Can someone please guide me what could go wrong with the above solution. OR give alternative solutions.

Thank You

Comment: The reason it doesn't work for you is because the quirks syntax you're referring to [started being used since libinput 1.12 version](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2018/06/libinput-and-its-device-quirks-files.html). 1.12 is an old libinput, however you tagged your question with 18.04, and [it has absolutely ancient 1.10.4 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/libinput). And in case you're wondering why would they change an API, quirks subsystem is not a configuration API, which is explicitly documented. See also the bottom half of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201038/266507).

Comment: @Hi-Angel it worked in my ubuntu 20.04 which I had earlier.

Comment: Right, because 20.04 is a more recent one, and doesn't have that ancient software, yet.

Comment: @Hi-Angel so, if I update to 20.04? WIll it work?

Comment: Maybe. 20.04 has [1.15.5 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/libinput), so the quirk syntax will be correct at least.

Comment: I have being experiencing the same problem. can somebody help?