# Trackpad tapping is blocked after motion 18.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, libinput

I've tried configuring two trackpads (laptop internal and Apple Magic Trackpad) using `synaptics` and `libinput` respectively, but still find that sometimes trackpad taps aren't detected.

Using `xinput --test`, I observe that sometimes taps aren't detected after a number of `motion` events. It's almost like some other gesture is blocking and waiting for some user interaction.

Is there a way I can disable *everything* other than tapping for a trackpad? I guess this might be device-specific?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

As a reference, the below stingy config wasn't resilient enough:

```
» xinput --list-props 9
Device 'Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2':
    Device Enabled (140):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (277): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (278): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (279):    0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (280):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (281):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (283):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (284):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (285):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (286):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (287):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (288):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (289):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (290):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (291):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (292): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (293):    0, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (294):    0, 1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (295):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (296):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (297): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (298): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (299): 1
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (300): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (266):    1452, 613
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (301):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (302):   0
```

```
» cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-magictrackpad.conf
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier      "Touchpads"
  Driver          "mtrack"
  MatchProduct    "Trackpad"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  # options...
    Option "Sensitivity" "0.55"
    Option "FingerHigh" "10"
    Option "FingerLow" "10"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    #Option "TapButton2" "3"
    #Option "TapButton3" "2"
    #Option "TapButton4" "0"
    Option "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
    Option "ClickTime" "25"
    Option "ScrollDistance" "75"
    Option "ScrollSmooth" "1"
    Option "TapDragEnable" "false"
```

Comment: You can debug it with `libinput debug-events --verbose` and `evemu-record` utilities. First one reports what libinput sees. The second one is more verbose and prints the actual events that the kernel sends down to userspace *(i.e. to libinput library)*. Then, if you see e.g. tap events in evemu but not libinput, then you know where's the problem. In this case I'd recommend to try latest released libinput *(Ubuntu likes to have ancient versions of software)*, and if it didn't help, [report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-bugs-touchpad)

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for the suggestion - I indeed see touch events correctly triggering (seemingly _always_) in `evemu-record` but not in `xinput --test`. Furthermore, `libinput debug-events` _only_ displays `POINTER_MOTION` and nothing more - so there are moments where `xinput --test` has events but nothing in `libinput debug-events`. If you have any advice on why these might be out of sync, or how to update `libinput` accordingly, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: About you seeing only `POINTER_MOTION`: you need to use `libinput debug-events` with the option `--verbose` to see touch events. Idk why they're not shown by default. Regarding upgrading to latest libinput: unfortunately there's no PPA, so one has to build from source code. It's easy though, you can [follow this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169155/266507), but please read the comments to know possible problems that the answer hasn't addressed.