# The touchpad of Asus tuf fx504 is not function properly on ubuntu 18.04 kernel 5.0.0-29-generic

Tags: 18.04, kernel, touchpad, asus, function-keys

Here the problem.
1. Clicking on touchpad only results in left-click even I click on the right side still produce the same as left-click
2. Hot ket to turn on/off touchpad is not working

I found some other similar questions like [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04),b but it was issued on the pass year when the kernel is still on 4.x version. Currently, the 5.0 kernel version officially came out, but the kind of problem is still exits. Is there any idea how to deal with this new kernel problem?

Many thanks