# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Touchpad detected but not working

Tags: touchpad

I have just updated my machine from Ubuntu 19 to 20.04 LTS and my touchpad is not working. It was not working on Ubuntu 19 either but it was also undetected.
However, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is detecting it. This is some of the output I get:

```
less /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003
```

I tried all of the solutions put forward in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) but to no avail. Can anyone help?

*Note.* My machine is an Acer Aspire E15 E5-575G-77FW.

EDIT: I am also aware of the fact that Acer laptops have a switch to enable/disable the touchpad.

Comment: Glad you found a fix! Feel free to answer your own question; it's a [common thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Exchange sites, as it marks the question answered (and can get you some reputation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a BIOS setting. In particular, there's an option called "touchpad mode" which can be set either to "advanced" or "basic". The system tells you that a certain driver is required to use advanced mode, so I switched it to basic and now it runs smoothly. I don't know which features I'm missing though.