# Touchpad not working after installation completed

Tags: touchpad, laptop

I recently bought the Chuwi LapBoook Pro. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it but the touchpad doesn't get recognized after the installation. In the installer and the live system I was able to use the touchpad normally without any problems. I also tried installing other distros after the ubuntu installation didn't worked. All of them (Arch, Manjaro, Debian, PopOS) had the same problem. Any ideas?

UPDATE: The touchpad now partially works. Sometimes after a boot it works fine sometimes not.

When the touchpad works, `libinput list-devices` outputs those two devices:

```
Device:           HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event4
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             119x63mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

Otherwise there are not there. So I think that the touchpad doesn't get recognized.

Comment: Does it work with a USB mouse plugged in? Also, which specific model is your laptop?

Comment: A USB mouse works well. Also the problem changed now.  The touchpad works now after some boots and after some not. I don't do anything while booting that would have an impact on that.

Comment: Does your laptop have a switch (or Fn + key combo) that disables the touchpad?

Comment: yes it does have one but pressing it makes no difference

Comment: I now updated the error with a little bit information.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of bugs for your touchpad with Linux. You can try a shotgun approach and install these: `xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse` Again, that's a shotgun and those all have various input device drivers among them.

Comment: Sadly that didn't worked. I guess I have to use Windows then.

Comment: try this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04